# How to make checkbox mandatory on register page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, forms, validation, register

I added a extra checkbox on register page, for `terms and conditions`, and i want to make it mandatory/required when i press on "create account" button.

this is my code:

```
<div class="register-button-custom">
        <label for="button">Do you agree?<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" >terms</a>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox required-entry" id="register-input-custom" />
        </label>    
    </div>
```

I already added this class for checkbox : `checkbox required-entry` but it's not working.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this checkbox mandatory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data-validate="{required:true}"` will do the trick

```
<div class="field choice newsletter">
        <label for="custom-terms" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Do you agree ?') ?></span></label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}" name="custom-terms" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Terms and contitions') ?>" id="register-input-custom" class="checkbox">
    </div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good luck !

Comment: i did the same but not working i can't see error message.

Comment: This does appear to make the input required, but shows no feedback when you leave it unchecked.

Comment: I have the same issue it doesn't show error message has anyone solved it ?

Comment: @SarfarajSipai I figured out why it does not show the error message. Here is my solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/338134/66769 (please upvote if it helps)

Answer (score -1):

As you are creating a custom field. I think use of this code will work for you:

```
<li class="control">
     <div class="input-box">
       <input type="checkbox" id="privacy_policy" name="privacy_policy" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Accept the privacy policy') ?>" class="checkbox required-entry">
     </div>
    <label for="is_subscribed"><?php echo $this->__('Accept the privacy policy') ?> (<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl( 6 ) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('privacy policy'); ?></a>)</label>
</li>
```

You can do text changes as per your requirement.

Comment: are you sure that it's not for magento 1?