# What is the proper format for checkbox validation in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, forms, validation, checkbox

Using 2.1.5, I have a custom front end form with a set of text elements built (roughly) as:

```
<div class="field my-field required">
    <label class="label" for="my-field">My Field:</label>
    <div class="control">
        <input  id="my-field" name="my-field" data-validate="{required:true}" size="20" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This looks fine and the validation displays properly. However, adding a checkbox input type isn't working the same way:

```
<div class="field my-checkbox required">
    <label class="label" for="my-checkbox">My checkbox:</label>
    <div class="control">
        <input  id="my-checkbox" name="my-checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The validation seems to be working, but there is no message displayed. If, using [How to make checkbox mandatory on register page in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162604/how-to-make-checkbox-mandatory-on-register-page-in-magento-2) as an example, I remove the `.control` div and add a `.choice` to the wrapper div, the validation works and the message is displayed properly, but all formatting based on the `.control` class is lost, making the checkbox element not have the same UI as the rest of the form:

```
<div class="field choice my-checkbox required">
    <label class="label" for="my-checkbox">My checkbox:</label>
    <input  id="my-checkbox" name="my-checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Is there a way to have the checkbox element use the same classes as the rest of the form, but also have the validation messaging visible?