# Magento 2 - No error message showing on required unchecked checkbox

Tags: magento2, validation

I added this required input to the contact form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="1" data-validate="{required:true}">
```

I made it required by adding this attribute `data-validate="{required:true}"`.

I also tried it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="1">

...

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#nl2go_subscribe_form": {
        "validation": {
            "rules": {
                "privacy_policy": {
                    "required": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

However, if a user does not check the checkbox and tries to submit, then there is no error showing. It just jumps to the checkbox.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about, this is exactly what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by debugging the code. It only shows a error message, if there is a label.
So I had to fix it like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="1" data-validate="{required:true}">
<label for="privacy_policy">&nbsp;Please accept our privacy policy</label>
```

Alternative:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privacy_policy" id="privacy_policy" value="1">
<label for="privacy_policy">&nbsp;Please accept our privacy policy</label>

...

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "#nl2go_subscribe_form": {
        "validation": {
            "rules": {
                "privacy_policy": {
                    "required": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```